# Mysql: Selecting id, then * on id is much faster than selecting *. Why?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a MySQL database table (roughly 100K rows):

id BIGINT(indexed), external_barcode VARCHAR(indexed), other simple columns, and a LongText column.

The LongText column is a JSON data dump. I save the large JSON objects because I will need to extract more of the data in the future.

When I run this query it takes 29+ seconds:

```
SELECT * FROM scraper_data WHERE external_barcode = '032429257284'
```

EXPLAIN

```
#id  select_type table          partitions type  possible_keys key  key_len ref  rows     filtered Extra
'1' 'SIMPLE'     'scraper_data' NULL       'ALL' NULL          NULL NULL    NULL '119902' '0.00'   'Using where'
```

This more complex query takes 0.00 seconds:

```
SELECT * FROM scraper_data WHERE id = (
    SELECT id FROM scraper_data WHERE external_barcode = '032429257284'
)
```

EXPLAIN

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'scraper_data', NULL, 'const', 'PRIMARY,id_UNIQUE', 'PRIMARY', '8', 'const', '1', '100.00', NULL
'2', 'SUBQUERY', 'scraper_data', NULL, 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '119902', '0.00', 'Using where'
```

Less than 6 rows are returned from these queries. Why is the LONGTEXT slowing down the first query given that its not being referenced in the where clause?

CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `scraper_data` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bzic` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `pzic` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `internal_barcode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_barcode_type` enum('upc','isbn','ean','gtin') DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_barcode` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `logo_image_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `variant_image_urls` text,
  `parent_brand` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_brand_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_part_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_model_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contributors` text,
  `content_info` text,
  `content_rating` text,
  `release_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `reviews` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ratings` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `internal_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adult_product` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `length` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `width` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scraped` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `scraped_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `scrape_attempt_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `processed_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `scrape_dump` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url_UNIQUE` (`url`),
  UNIQUE KEY `internal_barcode_UNIQUE` (`internal_barcode`),
  KEY `bzic` (`bzic`),
  KEY `pzic` (`pzic`),
  KEY `internal_barcode` (`internal_barcode`),
  KEY `external_barcode` (`external_barcode`,`external_barcode_type`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `scrape_attempt` (`bzic`,`scraped`,`scrape_attempt_timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=121674 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Show the EXAPLIN of both statemetns and the CREATE Table scraper_data

Comment: @nbk Updated post

Comment: Maybe you just run your second query after the first one. Hence, it uses the cached results of the first query?

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov The first query was taking to long so I built the second query as an optimization. They are not run together.

Answer (score 1):

The second query could benefit from the cache that already contains the result of the first query.

In addition in the second subquery you just select use two column (id,  external_barcode ) in these two column are in a index  all the query result is obtained  only with the index  scan while in the first query for retrieve all the data the query must scan all the tables  row ..

For avoiding the long time for the first query, you should add a proper index on  `external_barcode` column

```
create index my_idx  on scraper_data (external_barcode, id)
```

Comment: The two queries are not run together. The first query was taking to long, so I built the second query as an optimization. The post shows that external_barcode already has an index as well. Both queries use external_barcode in the where clause so the existence of an index should make no difference when comparing the performance difference of the two queries.

Comment: The external_barcode column in both queries is indexed and these queries are not run together. What is grabbed in the SELECT statement should have no effect on what is happening in the WHERE clause.

Comment: You have an index  with external_barcode, id ??  .. if this is true the subquery is resolved  just accessing the index  and only accessing at the the rows  related  tow the matching external_barcode...  in the first query ..  you need have also the others column  and for this the query must accessu to the table data .. Remember that the query optimizer  analyzes  all the query clause ..  firts the whenthen the from and  after the select  ..  and eval all the column  need  for solve the query .. and based  ond this perform the proper access  to the index (only) and/ or to the tables

Comment: The WHERE clause is exactly the same in both queries. One just SELECT *. The other SELECT id. The one that selects id is then wrapped with a second query that says SELECT * FROM id. The one doing double the work is much faster. This seems to reflect that what you SELECT from the results effects how fast the WHERE clause finds results.

Comment: but not the select  ... .. the outer query where where match the id returned  by the subqu ery  .. the id probaly is a primary key and have an index .. the subquery use the external_barcode  for match that have an index .. the first query perform  a full scan of the table for  get  all the columns values..

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are not equivalent, and your second query will throw an error if you have more than one row with that barcode:

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

This is probably what happens here: you do not actually get a result, just an error. Since MySQL can stop the full table scan as soon as it finds a second row, you can get this error faster than a correct result, including "0.00s" if those rows are among the first rows that are scanned (for example in `id`s 1 and 2).

From the execution plan, you can see that both do a full table scan (which, up to current versions, includes reading the blob field), and thus should perform similarly fast (as the first entry in your 2nd explain plan is neglectable for only a few rows).

So with a barcode that doesn't throw an error, both of your queries, as well as the corrected 2nd query (where you use `IN` instead of `=`),

```
SELECT * FROM scraper_data WHERE id IN (   -- IN instead of = !!
    SELECT id FROM scraper_data WHERE external_barcode = '032429257284'
)
```

as well as running your subquery

```
SELECT id FROM scraper_data WHERE external_barcode = '032429257284'
```

separately (which, if your assumption is correct, have to be even faster than your 2nd query) will have a similar (long) execution time.

As scaisEdge mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60242519), an index on `external_barcode` will improve the performance significantly, as you do not not need to do a full table scan, as well as you do not need to read the blob field. You actually have such an index, but you disabled it (`invisible`). You can simply reenable it by using

```
ALTER TABLE scraper_data ALTER INDEX `external_barcode` VISIBLE;
```